# Bayesian statistics (Finding a posterior distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Assume that when $\theta=1$, Y ~ N(1,$\sigma^2$) and when $\theta=2$, Y ~ N(2,$\sigma^2$). Let P($\theta=1$)=P($\theta=2$)=0.5

I'd like to find the posterior distribution. Here's the step I've done.

(1) Find the marginal probability distribution.

$P_{Y}(y) = P(Y|\theta=1)P(\theta=1) + P(Y|\theta=2)P(\theta=2)$

$=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-1}{\sigma}\right)^{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-2}{\sigma}\right)^{2}\right)$ (Simply => $0.5N(1,\sigma^2)+0.5N(2,\sigma^2)$)

It seems like a mixture distribution not a convolution?

(2) Explain what happens to the posterior distribution when $\sigma^2$ increases or decreases

Since $\theta$ can be 1 or 2, I express the posterior like the below.( But I'm not sure I'm doing it right.)

$P(\theta=i|Y) = \frac{P(Y|\theta=i)P(\theta=i)}{p(Y)}=\frac{0.5N(i,\sigma^2)}{0.5N(1,\sigma^2)+0.5N(2,\sigma^2)} = \frac{N(i,\sigma^2)}{N(1,\sigma^2)+N(2,\sigma^2)} = \frac{N(i,\sigma^2)}{N(3,2\sigma^2)}$

and I guess I got stuck at this point. I'm not sure about the result and even if I'm right, I still don't know what happens to the posterior distribution when $\sigma^2$ increases or decreases.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Even before making any calculation, imagine what happens after you see the $Y$ value. You know that if $Y$ is closer to 1 than it is to 2, $P(\theta = 1)$ will be of course favourite (greater than 50%). How much greater depends on $\sigma$: if it is very small, there is little chance to see, say, $Y=1.1$ coming from $N(2,\sigma)$, while if it's very big the chance will be higher.

Comment: You have also errors on the posterior: it should depend on $Y$. Maybe you were confused by your own notation, but terms should be of the $N(Y | i, \sigma^2)$ form and of course the sum you made at the denominator is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the marginal looks like a mixture of normal densities, because it is.  This is a property of the fact that the prior for $\theta$ has a discrete probability distribution, thus the marginal distribution will be a discrete mixture whose mixing weights are the probability masses for random variable $\theta$.

However, your posterior is not correct because the discrete mixture of normal distributions is not itself normally distributed, so you cannot assert that your denominator will be normal with mean $3$.  Because the prior for $\theta$ has support $\{1, 2\}$, the posterior for $\theta$ given $Y = y$ will also have the same support; i.e., the posterior for $\theta$ is a location-transformed Bernoulli random variable.  We have for instance

$$\Pr[\theta = 1 \mid Y = y] = \frac{f_Y(y \mid \theta = 1) \Pr[\theta = 1]}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{1}{1 + e^{(y-3/2)/\sigma^2}},$$ and
$$\Pr[\theta = 2 \mid Y = y] = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(y-3/2)/\sigma^2}}.$$  This tells us that if $y = 3/2$, the posterior probabilities are equal, which makes sense, since we observed a value that is exactly halfway between the prior means $1$ and $2$, so this data does not provide any additional information about which $\theta$ is more likely.  If $y > 3/2$, then $e^{-(y-3/2)/\sigma^2}$ becomes smaller, hence $\Pr[\theta = 2 \mid Y = y]$ increases.  If $\sigma$ is large, then this tends to make $e^{\pm (y-3/2)/\sigma^2}$ very small, making it less sensitive to changes to $y$ unless $y$ is extremely large.  Conversely, if $\sigma$ is very small, then $e^{\pm(y-3/2)/\sigma^2}$ will become more sensitive to changes in $y$.  To illustrate, here is a plot of the marginal for $Y$ for the choices $\sigma \in \{0.25, 0.45, 1\}$:

[image]

Blue is $0.25$, orange is $0.45$, and green is $1$.  You can see that when $\sigma$ is small, we have two distinguishable maxima centered around $1$ and $2$; as $\sigma$ increases, those maxima are lost because the normal densities "overlap" too much.

Now look at the posterior probability $\Pr[\theta = 2 \mid Y = y]$ for the same $\sigma$:

[image]

For $\sigma = 0.25$, the transition at $y = 3/2$ is very sharp, because as we saw from the marginal, $Y$ tends to be seen around $1$ or $2$, and less often around $3/2$.  So if we observe, say, $Y = 1.25$, the evidence is much more strong that $\theta = 1$ than $\theta = 2$.  But in the case $\sigma = 1$, the densities overlap much more, to the point where it is difficult to tell which $\theta$ is more likely.

Comment: I'm grateful! Now I see what mistakes I made and I guess I understand it clearly.